# How to create this hover effect on portfolio page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a homepage with this little effect on a hover.

It should look something like this:

[image]

How would you do this? My code does not work like it should.

```css
.stage_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
  height: auto;
}
.work {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}
.work img {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage_wrapper">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="work">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/350" class="media" alt="#" />
        <div class="caption">
          <div class="work_title">
            <h1>Something in 3 rows</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also post your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.work {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height:300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2d3e50;
  border: 10px solid #2a81b9;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.work span {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.work:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.work:hover img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <span>Some text</span>
  <img class="portfolio-image" src="http://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to have the picture before the hover. There should be a picture and after a hover the text should appear :)